# Null Pointer Using List and Servlets

Tags: java, list, servlets

I have a class with this method :

```
private List<Location> locations = new ArrayList();
```

I always get a null pointer exception at this line :

If i comment it off, i have an empty [] in my browser. So the problem is there i think.

After some debugging, i found out that Object s, it null. But i dont understand why. The debugger, doesn't continue after that line : see below ...

[image]

Comment: is the s object not null?

Comment: @Angelo If i return the list at `query.getResultList()` and change the return types to the list object Station, i get the full working results.Which means the query works.. But at the forloop, things go berserk.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: There is no reason for the list to be a field of your object. It should be a local variable of your `getstations()` method (which should be named `getStations()`).

Comment: @JBNizet please i don't understand what you mean could you elaborate more ? also please check my updated question please

Comment: You should remove `private List<Location> locations = new ArrayList();`from your class, and add `List<Location> locations = new ArrayList();` at the beginning of the `getstations()` method. You should also rename that method to `getStations()`, to respect the Java naming conventions. And the image you posted contradicts what you say: the list of stations contains many elements, none of which is null. Show us the Station class, and inspect the value of its fields (AddressGMapsLatitude, etc.) with your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find this in about 15 minutes is to step through a debugger.  You'll see exactly what's null in no time.

If any of those references are null you'll have a problem.

Not the cause, but why do you do this?

```
private List<Location> locations = new ArrayList();
```

Shouldn't it be this?

```
private List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
```

Comment: I don't see a local `locations`?

Comment: @duffymo please can you see the debugging info added ?

Comment: Not helpful.  Where'd you get that?  Use an IDE like IntelliJ and step through it.  You've already wasted an hour on a problem you can solve yourself in 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Either 's', 'locations' is null, or without seeing Station's code, it could also be that auto-unboxing fails if for example Station.getAddressGMapsLatitude() returns an uninitialized Double object instead of a primitive double.
But I suggest to check with the debugger (or add some logging).

Comment: i found out that s is null. Please see updated question. But can't fugure out why.

Comment: Debugging is a skill you need to practice.  Asking here isn't the way to do it.  If you can't figure it out, give up programming.